# Owncloud - ping - DNS

Tags: server, dns, ping, owncloud-server

I am very inexperienced with command line and only trying to install owncloud. I have put Ubuntu Server 14.04 on an old 32 bit laptop (thinkpad Z61m). I am trying to install owncloud and have tried:

`wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/community/xUbuntu_14.04/Release.key`

That only yields

`wget: unable to resolve host address 'download.opensuse.org' resolving download.opensuse.org (download.opensuse.org)...failed: name or service not known`.

I was starting to think maybe I have Internet access problem so i tried:

`ping www.google.com`

but that only lead to

`unknown host`

FYI, I did install the DNS server in the options on install of 14.04. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

The bind9 DNS server requires configuration.
I suspect you actually don't want to be running a DNS server and maybe you want to remove it.
Otherwise please use the [Ubuntu Serverguide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dns.html) as a reference for configuring it.

Comment: So I shouldn't worry that ping [any URL] "unknown host" is symptom of some internet access problem - its a server config error

Comment: Good point. Yes, you should. Try `ping 8.8.8.8` i.e. ping a Google name server by IP address.

Comment: that says "network unreachable" (assuming u literally meant 8.8.8.8)

Comment: Do you observe any configured network card with the `ifconfig` command? While you were installing Ubuntu server did it not find and configure the network card?

Comment: I am on a wireless network - ifconfig gives me about 20 lines of text 'lo" and "virbr0" - can't see any reference to a network card

Comment: I don't remember any questions about a network card during the installation

Comment: O.K., seems you have no network and your wireless NIC is not configured.

Comment: Reinstalled Ubuntu server with an ethernet cable attached ....problems (at least this one) now fixed - your help is appreciated